# How to check if the user input is a number N=4k+1 and if not, to ask for a repeated input in C

Tags: c

The title is kinda lame, but here's the explanation:

I want to check if the user input (integer) is in this form --> N = 4k + 1 (number 1, 5, 9, 13 and so on) and if the input isn't one of those numbers, I want keep asking the user to input the number until it's right.

I tried to do it like this:

I made a loop that checks if N-1 can be divided by 2, and if yes, that's my N. BUT, of course, it doesn't work. N-1 is supposed to be an even number (if the correct N is entered) so is there a way to check that somehow, and if it's not right to keep looping the "enter a number" part?

```
int N, k;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &N)
    k=(N-1);

     /* checking */
     while (k%2 != 0)
     {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &N);
     }
```

The problem with this code is that when you enter the right number, it works fine, BUT when you input a wrong number, and afterwards the right number, it keeps looping the "Enter a number" part. How to fix this?

Comment: `N%4 == 1` should do it.

Comment: Why are you checking if `(N-1)` can be divided by 2? Based on your equation, shouldn't it be 4? Also, after scanning again in the while loop, you'll have to redo the calculation for `k`, which you're not doing.

Comment: Check your formula implementation: `1==4*(1-1) + 1`, `5 != 4 * (5-1) + 1`.

Comment: k%2 is wrong slightly, glance at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put both the prompt and the check inside the same loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int args, char** argv) {
    int N, k;

    k = 1;  // this is here just to get the loop going,

    while (k%2 != 0) {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &N);
        k=(N-1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'd like to point out, however, that your test is incorrect; half of all numbers that are divisible by 2 will not be correct answers to the task as-stated.  I've only fixed the looping; not the logic.  (There are several fine comments about fixing the math; take note of them.)

I've added a note about the purpose of the `k = 1;` line.  As noted, it's there to prevent the `while()` loop from immediately exiting.  I think you were hung up on calculating `k` from `N`, which is what you want to do *in general*, but you can supply a "fake" `k` so that `k` can serve as the loop condition before any input has been provided.